# ¿Saben por qué me cambia el signo "<" por ">" al momento de usar la función typewrite()?

Tags: python, funciones

Hice un pequeño programa con la librería pyautoguide de python, pero tengo un problema al momento de usar la función typewrite().

```
import pyautogui as pg
import time

pg.hotkey("win","r")
pg.typewrite("notepad\n")
time.sleep(1)
pg.typewrite("<")
```

En la última línea quiero que en el bloc de notas escriba el signo "<" con `pg.typewrite("<")` pero en la salida lo que escribe en el bloc de notas es el signo ">".[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me pueden ayudar, de antemano les agradecería mucho.

Comment: Se supone que tienes que presionar y mantener 'shift' para obtener el caracter superior. Por ejemplo `with pg.hold('shift'): pg.press('6')` obtengo `&`. Me funciona con todo el teclado, menos con `<`. Muy curioso.